# I want Texts on this Colour-Filled Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-manipulation

I want to be able to write simple text, maths and reach text in this colour-filled tikz image. I want to be able to choose text colours, align the text and be able to shadow the text within the rectangular pane.

**What I Have**

Here is [image: what I have]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!5]
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % slant rectangle
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10,rotate=30] (3.2,2.8) -- ++ (2.5,0) to[bend right] ++ (0.65,0.4) --++ (-.05,-1.4) to[bend right] ++ (-0.65,0.4) -- ++ (-2.5,0) -- cycle;

        %% small circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.4cm);
        \fill[Cyan] (1.5,3.75) circle (0.2cm);

        %%% Big Rectangles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10, rounded corners=10] (5.0,4.4) rectangle (11.6,7.6);
        \fill[Cyan,rounded corners=10]  (4.8,4.8) rectangle (11.3,7.3);

        %% big circles
        \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10] (5.5,6) circle (1.6);
        \fill [Cyan](5.5,6) circle (0.9cm);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What I Want**

Here is a picture of what I want it to [image: look like]. I put this texts with Microsoft paint to illustrate what I want.

Comment: Create a node with a minipage of the correct size inside and type your text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add node with text! For example, fragment with this node is:

```
    %%% Big Rectangles
    \shade[shading=ball, ball color = gray!10, rounded corners=10] (5.0,4.4) 
        rectangle (11.6,7.6);
    \fill[Cyan,rounded corners=10]  (4.8,4.8) rectangle (11.3,7.3)
        node[text width=38mm, align=left,       % <--- added
             font=\small\sffamily, text=black,
             below left]
         {{\large\itshape\textbf{Heading}}\\
           This is a description of what I want to do.
           I also want to include math:\\
           $a^2+b^2=c^2$
         } ;
```

[image]

Styling of text I left to you :-)